# Trouble Inserting a Article to Database Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting

I have created a blog that can post articles. **It works fine in localhost**. But When I deploy my project to Shared hosting only articles with 100 characters inserted, other articles gives me this error:

*The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.*

`@csrf` is added
`method="post"`
also `enctype="multipart/form-data"` added

Comment: check this url and check your route `The GET method is not supported for this route`

Comment: both method and route must be POST. May be one of them is GET. If both of them are POST then clean cache by running 'php artisan optimize' from terminal

Comment: url and the methods ate in the same type "post", in for smaller articles it works fines, but articles are bigger it shows errors.

Comment: @Psycho did that no use

Comment: maybe cache issue run php artisan optimize command in terminal

Comment: may be error is misleading, edit your question and add database table structure

Comment: id = big int, title->text, content->longtext